# How to return RSA key in jwks_uri endpoint for OpenID Connect Discovery

Tags: python, google-oauth, jwt, openid-connect, openid-provider

Working on the discovery part of an OpenID Connect provider, I'm a bit confused about how to properly return my *public* *keys*. My problem is specifically with the `modulus (n)` and the `exponent (e)` values.

The initial values of both are:

```
n = 124692971944797177402996703053303877641609106436730124136075828918287037758927191447826707233876916396730936365584704201525802806009892366608834910101419219957891196104538322266555160652329444921468362525907130134965311064068870381940624996449410632960760491317833379253431879193412822078872504618021680609253

e = 65537
```

So, what I understand reading [here](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-jones-json-web-key-00.html#anchor8), just need to base64url encode both.

*(Example in Python)*

```
n = urlsafe_b64encode(str(n))
e = urlsafe_b64encode(str(e))

n = "MTI0NjkyOTcxOTQ0Nzk3MTc3NDAyOTk2NzAzMDUzMzAzODc3NjQxNjA5MTA2NDM2NzMwMTI0MTM2MDc1ODI4OTE4Mjg3MDM3NzU4OTI3MTkxNDQ3ODI2NzA3MjMzODc2OTE2Mzk2NzMwOTM2MzY1NTg0NzA0MjAxNTI1ODAyODA2MDA5ODkyMzY2NjA4ODM0OTEwMTAxNDE5MjE5OTU3ODkxMTk2MTA0NTM4MzIyMjY2NTU1MTYwNjUyMzI5NDQ0OTIxNDY4MzYyNTI1OTA3MTMwMTM0OTY1MzExMDY0MDY4ODcwMzgxOTQwNjI0OTk2NDQ5NDEwNjMyOTYwNzYwNDkxMzE3ODMzMzc5MjUzNDMxODc5MTkzNDEyODIyMDc4ODcyNTA0NjE4MDIxNjgwNjA5MjUz"
e = "NjU1Mzc="
```

In what am I wrong? Because, for example, [google keys](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs) have a different encoding.

*(Google key values)*

```
n = "rl1iVsRbhod-gDJj2SDs94lk5iY0QYXV5HIPtjcx4KmIlmq-cdmfLteTeIHFsO5c6hKUt8R3uZzaQNgF3fKt700fT4m6tU23qK4EoLlx9Z_uSajtpMajdmX_FOdyHyQgcn0tj3YqPeYCOTBhRVNoLIenf9vy0hfFy71lcPhylnE",
e = "AQAB"
```

Am I missing something? Thanks for your time.

*PD: [The project I'm working on](https://github.com/juanifioren/django-oidc-provider).*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're base64url-encoding the decimal representation of the values but you should base64url-encode the octet value, i.e. the big-endian byte sequence as defined here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-6.3.1.1 and here https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-2

> Base64urlUInt
>
> The representation of a positive or zero integer value as the
> base64url encoding of the value's unsigned big-endian
> representation as an octet sequence.  The octet sequence MUST
> utilize the minimum number of octets needed to represent the
> value.  Zero is represented as BASE64URL(single zero-valued
> octet), which is "AA".

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_bytes_length(n):
    """ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes"""
    return ((n).bit_length() + 7) // 8

def b64_enc(n, l):
    n = n.to_bytes(l, 'big')
    return base64.b64encode(n)

>>> b64_enc(65537, get_bytes_length(65537))
>>> b'AQAB'
```

Comment: explain what you trying to do.