# Get the big-endian byte sequence of integer in Python

Tags: python, integer, rsa

Based on this post: [How to return RSA key in jwks_uri endpoint for OpenID Connect Discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30537328/how-to-return-rsa-key-in-jwks-uri-endpoint-for-openid-connect-discovery)

I need to **base64url-encode** the **octet value** of this two numbers:

```
n = 124692971944797177402996703053303877641609106436730124136075828918287037758927191447826707233876916396730936365584704201525802806009892366608834910101419219957891196104538322266555160652329444921468362525907130134965311064068870381940624996449410632960760491317833379253431879193412822078872504618021680609253

e = 65537
```

> The "n" (modulus) parameter contains the modulus value for the RSA public key.  It is represented as a Base64urlUInt-encoded value.
>   Note that implementers have found that some cryptographic libraries
>   prefix an extra zero-valued octet to the modulus representations they
>   return, for instance, returning 257 octets for a 2048-bit key, rather
>   than 256.  Implementations using such libraries will need to take
>   care to omit the extra octet from the base64url-encoded
>   representation.
>
> The "e" (exponent) parameter contains the exponent value for the RSA
>   public key.  It is represented as a Base64urlUInt-encoded value.
>   For instance, when representing the value 65537, the octet sequence
>   to be base64url-encoded MUST consist of the three octets [1, 0, 1];
>   the resulting representation for this value is "AQAB".

For example, a valid encode should look like this: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs

¿How could I do this in Python?

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching the best way to tackle this problem, using [pyjwkest](https://github.com/rohe/pyjwkest) seems to be a good one instead of creating my own function.

```
pip install pyjwkest
```

Then we use `long_to_base64` function for this

```
>>> from jwkest import long_to_base64
>>> long_to_base64(65537)
'AQAB'
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately pack() doesn't support numbers that big, and int.to_bytes() is only supported in Python 3, so we'll have to pack them ourselves before encoding. Inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730927/convert-python-long-int-to-fixed-size-byte-array) I came to a solution by converting to a hex string first:

```
import math
import base64

def Base64urlUInt(n):
    # fromhex() needs an even number of hex characters,
    # so when converting our number to hex we need to give it an even
    # length. (2 characters per byte, 8 bits per byte)
    length = int(math.ceil(n.bit_length() / 8.0)) * 2
    fmt = '%%0%dx' % length
    packed = bytearray.fromhex(fmt % n)
    return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(packed).rstrip('=')
```

Resulting in:

```
n = 124692971944797177402996703053303877641609106436730124136075828918287037758927191447826707233876916396730936365584704201525802806009892366608834910101419219957891196104538322266555160652329444921468362525907130134965311064068870381940624996449410632960760491317833379253431879193412822078872504618021680609253
e = 65537

Base64urlUInt(n) == 'sZGVa39dSmJ5c7mbOsJZaq62MVjPD3xNPb-Aw3VJznk6piF5GGgdMoQmAjNmANVBBpPUyQU2SEHgXQvp6j52E662umdV2xU-1ETzn2dW23jtdTFPHRG4BFZz7m14MXX9i0QqgWVnTRy-DD5VITkFZvBqCEzWjT_y47DYD2Dod-U'
Base64urlUInt(e) == 'AQAB'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different bit of Python code for the task, taken from `rsalette`

```
def bytes_to_int(data):
    """Convert bytes to an integer"""
    hexy = binascii.hexlify(data)
    hexy = b'0'*(len(hexy)%2) + hexy
    return int(hexy, 16)

def b64_to_int(data):
    """Convert urlsafe_b64encode(data) to an integer"""
    return bytes_to_int(urlsafe_b64decode(data))

def int_to_bytes(integer):
    hexy = as_binary('%x' % integer)
    hexy = b'0'*(len(hexy)%2) + hexy
    data = binascii.unhexlify(hexy)
    return data

def int_to_b64(integer):
    """Convert an integer to urlsafe_b64encode() data"""
    return urlsafe_b64encode(int_to_bytes(integer))

def as_binary(text):
    return text.encode('latin1')
```